# Cannot detect any meaningful timing difference in PHP (constant timing attack)

Tags: php, security, constant-time, timing-attack

There's quite a few articles around PHP stating that constant timing attacks are possible when doing direct string comparisons. I've written some sample code to try and determine the order of magnitude difference but it's showing that it's not always the case that one is quicker than the other, even when doing millions of tests.

You would expect the first iteration active time to be quicker, as the first character is wrong in the string and thus the comparison can bail out, but it's not always the case.

```
$target = 'hello-world';
$comparison = ['Xello-world', 'hello-worlX'];

foreach($comparison as $x){
    $time = 0;
    $total = 500000;
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
        $start = microtime(true);

        /** Actually perform the comparison */
        $result = ($target === $comparison);
        $end = microtime(true);

        /** Add up so we can compute the average **/
        $time += $end - $start;
    }

    echo "Duration for $x: " . ($time / $total) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `$result = ($target === $comparison);` needs to be `$result = ($target === $x);`.Isn't it?

Comment: As well as you need to check value of `var_dump($result);`to check actually it's giving bool(yes) anytime?(comparison gave success even they are not matched)

Comment: Thanks so much @AlivetoDie - I can't believe I missed that. I guess that's what happens when you're up too late programming haha. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not a quesiton

Comment: I think you need to re-read what timing attacks are about and potentially also about constant time comparisons.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack
https://blog.1password.com/constant-time-comparisons/